# Javascript array is undefined... and I'm not sure why

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to translate a PHP class into JavaScript. The only thing I'm having trouble with is getting an item out of an array variable. I've created a simple jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YznSE/7/). I cannot figure out why it won't work.

(EDIT: I updated this code to better reflect what I'm doing. Sorry for the previous mistake.)

```
function tattooEightBall() {

this.subjects = ['a bear', 'a tiger', 'a sailor'];

this.prediction = make_prediction();

var that = this;



function array_random_pick(somearray) {
      //return array[array_rand(array)];
      var length = somearray.length;

      var random = somearray[Math.floor(Math.random()*somearray.length)];
    return random;


}


function make_prediction() {

    var prediction = array_random_pick(this.subjects);
    return prediction;
}

}
var test = tattooEightBall();
document.write(test.prediction);
```

​

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine here, you are simple not calling

```
classname();
```

After you define the function.

**Update**

When you make a call to *make_prediction* , *this* will not be in scope. You are right on the money creating a *that* variable, use it on *make_prediction* :

```
var that = this;

this.prediction = make_prediction();

function make_prediction() {
  var prediction = ''; //initialize it

  prediction = prediction + array_random_pick(that.subjects);
  return prediction;
}
```

You can see a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/zKcpC/

This is actually pretty complex and I believe someone with more experience in Javascript may be able to clarify the situation.

Edit2: Douglas Crockfords explains it with these words:

> By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make
>   the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for
>   an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to
>   be set incorrectly for inner functions.

To see the complete article head to: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Ha! Sorry I stripped down the code too much and I guess it removed my problem. I've revised the code with a more accurate version of my code (which doesn't work):
http://jsfiddle.net/YznSE/7/

Comment: Emerson, so it still doesn't work? If you could provide the page you are working on, or the exact function/usage on fiddle you have, we may be able to help.

Comment: You didn't return anything from tattooEightBall. Try adding a return this; at the end of the function.

Comment: AHA. That made it work on jsfiddle, but for some reason I can't get my actual code to work. Here's a newer jsfiddle (I can't figure out why THIS won't work exactly the same way!). I get an error saying that the "length" property of my "subjects" array is undefined:
http://jsfiddle.net/wpZ5A/

Comment: @Emerson - take a look at my answer for a working jsFiddle that makes a class.  It looks to me like you don't understand how the `this` operator works in javascript.  If you just call a plain javascript function, then `this` is set back to `window` in that function.  You either have to use `fn.apply(this, ...)` or `obj.fn(...)` to cause the value of `this` to be set properly.  In your fiddle, when you call `make_prediction()`, it looses the value of `this` so then that value isn't set properly inside of the function and you get a javascript error.

Comment: I got it to work!! Thanks everyone! Everyone's comments were very useful. However I had made one additional mistake that hasn't been mentioned: the ORDER of my `that` var declaration. It was after the call to the make_prediction method, and THIS is why I couldn't get it to work. I'm accustomed to PHP where these kinds of ordering issues come up less often. Thans again!

Answer (score 0):

You never call `classname`.  Seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
(function classname() {

this.list = [];
this.list[0] = "tiger";
this.list[1] = "lion";
this.list[2] = "bear";

function pickone(somearray) {
    var length = somearray.length;          
    var random  = somearray[Math.floor(Math.random()*length)];
    return random;
}


var random_item = pickone(this.list);

document.write(random_item);

}());
```

Were you actually calling the `classname` function?  Note I wrapped your code block in:

```
([your_code]());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly with the class structure you were using so I made some guesses, but this code works by creating a classname object that has instance data and a `pickone` method:

```
function classname() {

    this.list = [];
    this.list[0] = "tiger";
    this.list[1] = "lion";
    this.list[2] = "bear";

    this.pickone = function() {
        var length = this.list.length;          
        var random  = this.list[Math.floor(Math.random()*length)];
        return random;
    }
}

var cls = new classname();
var random = cls.pickone();
```

You can play with it interactively here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ReL2h/.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/YznSE/6/ You just didn't call `classname()`. If you don't call it, nothing will happen ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make it into a self-executing function like this:

```
(function classname() {

this.list = [];
this.list[0] = "tiger";
this.list[1] = "lion";
this.list[2] = "bear";

function pickone(somearray) {
    var length = somearray.length; //<---WHY ISN'T THIS DEFINED??       
    var random = somearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)];
    return random;
}


var random_item = pickone(this.list);

document.write(random_item);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = tattooEightBall();
document.write(test.prediction);
```

Should be:

```
var test = new tattooEightBall(); //forgot new keyword to create object
document.write(test.prediction()); // forgot parens to fire method
```

and:

```
this.prediction = make_prediction();
```

Should be:

```
this.prediction = make_prediction;
```